# Conditional access of array elements

Tags: python, arrays, function, if-statement

I have a data vector `data = [x for x in range(0,999)]` what I want to do is that to, access elements in `data` according to a given `value` e.g if `value=10` access 0th index of `data` and if `value=20` access 1st index of `data`. It is supoused to be something like this:

```
def get_data(value):
if value ==10:
    return data[0]
elif value == 20:
    return data[1]
elif value ==30:
    return data[2]
```

But in reality, i will have really big data and I cannot keep putting `elif` statements. Is there any efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You can check [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python), may help you.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be dividing the `value` to `10` and then just substract `1` from result.

```
return data[value//10 - 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to solve your problem.

```
def get_data(value):
     return {
         10: data[0],
         20: data[1],
         30: data[2]
     }.get(value, data[3])   #data[3] will be the default value.
```

Comment: But my array [10,20,30,.....] is really large. it is not possible to assign each value to dictionary manually